# Get logged in user with relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

How can I get the logged in user with a relationship?

My `User.php` class looks like this:

```
class User {
    public function messages() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Message');
    }
}
```

I want to get the logged in user along with all of their messages.

I tried:

```
Auth::user()->with('messages')->get();
```

But this returned a list of *all* users and not just the logged in one.

How can I do this?

Comment: `Auth::user()->messages`

Comment: That *only* gets their messages though. I want to get the user *and* their messages.

Comment: The user is at `Auth::user()` and the `messages` in the messages attribute. I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish that this won't suit.

Comment: I want to return *both* the user and their messages. If I do `Auth::user()->messages` it *only* returns their messages.

Comment: If you return `Auth::user()`, it will have the messages at the `messages` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$user = Auth::user()->load('messages');
```

So now, you can get the user's messages using something like this:

```
$messages = $user->messages;
```